# Transpose of conjugate transpose?

Tags: matrices, transpose

What is the transpose of a conjugate transpose? Let's say we have a matrix $A$ and its conjugate transpose $A^{*}$, would the transpose of the conjugate transpose be the conjugate of $A$, i.e. $\bar{A}$?

Would one represent that as follows:

$A^{*T} = \bar{A}$

I have seen this written out as numpy code, but I don't know how to represent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transpose of the transpose is the original matrix, as transposition is an involution.

So you're right, the transpose of the conjugate transpose of a matrix $A$ is just the conjugate $\bar A$, although I think this notation is not heavily used in linear algebra.

Comment: Which notation do you mean? The $A^{*T} = \bar{A}$, then how would one represent that?

Comment: Its fine. For me, $\bar A$ is not heavily used in linear algebra.

Comment: I understand, thank you.